# Overriding a method in a subclass while retaining the contents of the superclass method

Tags: java

In java, is there any way to do override a superclass method in a subclass while retaining the contents of the superclass method? Something like this:

```
class Person { 

public void update(){
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
    }

} 

class Student extends person {

    @Override
    public void update(){
        super().update();
        statement 3; 
        statement 4;

    }
}
```

such that calling update() on a Student would cause Statements 1, 2, 3 and 4 to be executed?

Comment: just call it with super.update(); super() is the default mainclass constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Place `super.update()` in the beginning of the subclass method.